# how to retrieve the value of a kvp in c sharp, using the text of the key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I have various values and names stored in a db table, that my code will use for various tasks.

These are read into a kvp , so that I can get to the right value from its key when I need to.

As far as I've seen so far, getting to the value using the index of the key is easy, but can I get in via the name of the key instead

```
kvp["name of key"].value
```

for instance?

I know any key/values stored in the config files can be accessed as

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queryLoadJobDataDetails"]
```

but as I need to read these values in as I go, adding them to web.config is a bit pointless!

Comment: You say they're stored in a database table, which suggests you should be doing a query... or possibly populating a `Dictionary<string, string>`...

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet.   you should do the query and use it to populate dictionary.  Once you have the dictionary you should be able to do dict["keyName"]  to get the value of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just Guessing what you need here:

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;


 //
 IDictionary<string, object> kvps = new Dictionary<string, object>();

 kvps.Add("something", 42);
 kvps.Add("else", "entirely");

 object i = kvps["something"];
 string s = kvps["else"] as string;
```

Also look at [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
 object v;
 if (kvps.TryGetValue("missing", ref v))
     Console.WriteLine("Not missing: {0}", v);
```